# Breadcrumbs for cms page?

Tags: breadcrumbs

I want to add breadcrumbs for my faq page like this:

> Home -> Pages -> FAQ

but when I call breadcrumb from `Magento_Theme` module, it's just show `Home -> FAQ`.

Any suggestions for this issue?

Many thanks.

Comment: which magento  version

Comment: i'm using version 2.1

Answer (score 1):

Try below in your layout file

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true"/>
<referenceContainer name="page.top">
    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs.cms">
        <action method="addCrumb">
            <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Home</argument>
            <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
                <item name="link" xsi:type="string">/</item>
            </argument>
        </action> 
        <action method="addCrumb">
            <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Pages</argument>
            <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Pages</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Pages</item>
            </argument>
        </action>
        <action method="addCrumb">
            <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">FAQ</argument>
            <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Faq</item> 
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Faq</item> 
            </argument>
        </action>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```